# Print total count for a matching pattern

Tags: awk

I use an API to fetch a billion or so records which I run through `awk` to filter and pipe to `wc -l` to count the records. I'm currently doing this successfully:

```
$apiCall | awk '$1=="xx"' | wc -l > file
```

But I think combining an AWK command will consume less compute than piping to `wc -l`, something like this:

```
$apiCall | awk '$1=="xx" && END{print NR}' > file
```

But this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is right, but the right syntax for doing that in `awk` could be do to

```
$apiCall | awk '$1=="xx"{ count++ }END{ print count }'
```

Since `awk` is `pattern { action }` based, once we match the pattern of `xx` in the first column, we do the action part of increment a counter on each occurrence and when we finish processing the file, in the `END` clause we print out the final count. Re-direct the output to a file at the end with `> file` as needed.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you for both the code and lesson!

Comment: @Steve If this solves your issue, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may find that:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -Ec '^[[:blank:]]*xx([[:blank:]]|$)'
```

is considerably quicker as it avoids the overhead of `awk` having to interpret a higher level language.

We're using `LC_ALL=C` to simplify the text interpretation. That also means that only SPC and TAB are understood as delimiter, but that's the case of many `awk` implementations as well regardless of the locale.

Some timings on a GNU/Linux amd64 multi-core system from `zsh`:

```
$ (repeat 3000 printf '%s\n' {{,xx}{1..1000},xx}" blah blah blah")> a
$ wc a
  6003000  24012000 119412000 a
$ time LC_ALL=C grep -Ec '^[[:blank:]]*xx([[:blank:]]|$)' < a
3000
LC_ALL=C grep -Ec '^[[:blank:]]*xx([[:blank:]]|$)' < a  0.15s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 0.175 total
$ time gawk '$1=="xx"{n++};END{print n}' < a
3000
gawk '$1=="xx"{n++};END{print n}' < a  2.00s user 0.05s system 99% cpu 2.055 total
$ time LC_ALL=C gawk '$1=="xx"{n++};END{print n}' < a
3000
LC_ALL=C gawk '$1=="xx"{n++};END{print n}' < a  1.96s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 1.985 total
$ time mawk '$1=="xx"{n++};END{print n}' < a
3000
mawk '$1=="xx"{n++};END{print n}' < a  1.23s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 1.277 total
$ time gawk '$1=="xx"' < a | wc -l
3000
gawk '$1=="xx"' < a  1.91s user 0.05s system 99% cpu 1.967 total
wc -l  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.967 total
```